# Is there a class teardown counterpart to +initialize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm sure it is wishful thinking, but is there a counterpart to `+initialize` that will automatically get called when all instances of a class have been dealloc'ed?

I allocate a singleton object in +initialize, which is called before my first class instance gets alloc'ed.  I would love to be able to release the object once my class instances have all been deallocated.  However, if my objects of my class ever get reallocated, then I would need `+initialize` to get called again.  I suspect Cocoa doesn't do that level of class management and it is probably up to me to wrap my class in a class manager class...

Am I correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I.e. what resource are you trying to manage that indicates you need this pattern?

Comment: For example, I have a series of buttons.  They share some images, stored as a singleton.  The singleton is setup in the +initialize call.  If you release all the buttons, and they are deallocated, then I would like the shared images to be released too.  Having a teardown counterpart to +initialize would let me do that.  Otherwise, I'll have to do my own management of the number of objects using the shared images and then release them when the count of client objects go to zero.

Comment: Why not simply create the image before you create the buttons, pass the images to the buttons via their init methods, and release the image you created?  Let the buttons do the normal retain/release and you don't have to worry about a singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't.

I recommend just not removing a singleton, there's almost no point because it's *just one object*, which isn't going to take a lot of space.

If you really need this behavior, just override `+alloc` and `-dealloc` to count the current instances. (or `-finalize` in a garbage collected environment).

Comment: “Anyway, +initialize gets called when the class is loaded into memory.” You're thinking of `load`. `initialize` gets called when a class (or a subclass of it) receives its first message. See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/ and http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/06/iniailize-can-be-executed-multiple-times-load-not-so-much/

Answer (score 0):

This only works nicely under ARC (with zeroing weak references, i.e. iOS5), but a nice way to do something like this is by having class methods on the object (without an extra singleton), i.e.:

```
+ (id)someResource
{
    __weak static id resource;
    if (!obj)
    {
        return resource;
    }
    else
    {
        id tmpResource = [SomeResource resource];
        resource = tmpResource;
        return resource;
    }
}
```

`+someResource` will always return the same object as long as anyone else is holding on to `resource`, but as soon as no one else is using it goes away.